# Regress in MATLAB vs My code for multiple linear regression

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to do a multiple linear regression using the data available in MATLAB as 'carsmall' file. My aim is to predict mileage as a function of weight and horsepower.

Basically, y =w1*x1 +w2*x2 +b; I did write the below MATLAB code to perform gradient descent. I observed that my cost function denoted by J is indeed decreasing as the iterations progress.

However, my solution for [w1 w2 b] is not matching with MATLAB's inbuilt function "regress". Can someone let me know what is causing this issue?

```
%% Multiple linear regression
clc;
clear;
close all;

%% Load the carsmall data set. Identify weight and horsepower as predictors and mileage as the response.

load carsmall;
x1 = Weight;
x2 = Horsepower;
y = MPG;   % mileage

num_features =2;
%% Multiple linear regression

% We need a linear estimator: y_est =w1*x1+w2*x2 +b;
% Cost function is the mean squared error:  J = mean(y -y_est).^2;

%% initializations 
w_vec = zeros(num_features,1);
b = 0;
x_vec =[x1 x2];
num_iter =100000;

%% Linear regression 
J_vals =[];
for iter =1: num_iter
%% computing derivatives
alpha =1;
y_est =x_vec*w_vec +b;
if iter >1 && abs(J- J_new ) < 1e-8
    break;
end
J = mean((y-y_est).^2,'omitnan');
J_vals =[J_vals J]; % Just storing the cost values to see if its decreasing.
M = repmat(y-y_est,1,num_features);  % 2 columns of y-y_est 
dJ_dW = -mean(M.*x_vec,1,'omitnan')';% derivative w.r.t w1 and w2.
dJ_db = -mean(y-y_est,'omitnan');    % derivative w.r.t b


while (true)
    w_new = w_vec -alpha*dJ_dW;
    b_new = b -alpha*dJ_db;
    J_new = mean((y-(x_vec*w_new +b_new)).^2,'omitnan');
    %% Make alpha lower by half if J (cost) is not decreasing.
    if J_new < J 
        w_vec = w_new;
        b = b_new;
        break;
    else
        alpha = 0.5*alpha;
    end
end
end
Str1 = sprintf('w vector is [%f, %f].\n',w_vec(1),w_vec(2));
disp(Str1);
Str2 = sprintf('b is %f. \n',b);
disp(Str2);

%% Plot to see if we are doing right?
scatter3(x1,x2,y,'filled');
hold on;
[X1,X2] =meshgrid(min(x1):100: max(x1), min(x2):100:max(x2));
Y_EST = w_vec(1)*X1 +w_vec(2)*X2 +b;

mesh(X1,X2,Y_EST)
xlabel('Weight')
ylabel('Horsepower')
zlabel('MPG')
view(50,10)
hold off

%% Using MATLAB inbuilt function

X_matlab = [ones(size(x1)) x1 x2];
coeff = regress(y,X_matlab)    % Removes NaN data

figure;
scatter3(x1,x2,y,'filled');
hold on;
[X1,X2] =meshgrid(min(x1):100: max(x1), min(x2):100:max(x2));
Y_EST = coeff(2)*X1 +coeff(3)*X2 +coeff(1);

mesh(X1,X2,Y_EST)
xlabel('Weight')
ylabel('Horsepower')
zlabel('MPG')
view(50,10)
hold off
```

I tried plotting the resulting 3D plots to compare the results of my code vs MATLAB's regress. It seems regress is better. Also, their cost is less compared to the cost of my solution.